# Implementing an automatic failback in SQL Server 2019 Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I am looking at how best to implement an automatic failback in one of our AGs. Can anyone advise please, on how best to go about this? My thoughts are as follows:

- a failover has happened for whatever reason in the first place.
- that reason needs to be investigated and fixed before a failback should be permitted
- perhaps setup a scheduled SQL Agent job (don't know how yet :-) ) to run every night (for example) which will check that the preferred primary node is the current primary. If not, is it available for a failover (again don't know how yet), and if it is, then failback to it in the event that it is not the current primary.
- Does this sound right?

**OR** is there a straightforward way to do this in FCM? The setting in the Failover tab in the Role Properties page in FCM seems to be doing nothing, even though it's set to allow failback immediately. Am I getting this wrong? Otherwise what is the purpose of that setting?

I'd appreciate any thoughts and possibly pointer to any helpful article please.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking at how best to implement an automatic failback in one of our AGs. Can anyone advise please, on how best to go about this?

I would advise against doing this at all. In a proper setup, you shouldn't care where the AG is living, with the exception of a true disaster situation in which case it should be of more importance to make sure the environment is recovered or rebuilt to get out of that situation.

> a failover has happened for whatever reason in the first place. that reason needs to be investigated and fixed before a failback should be permitted

Absolutely spot on.

> perhaps setup a scheduled SQL Agent job [...] which will check that the preferred primary node is the current primary.

There shouldn't be a preference. In the cluster, there is the notion of a preference and this is for failover, however any of those should be fine. What does it matter if it's running on Node1, Node2, or Node3? If there is an environment specific reason to run on a specific node, then it would make more sense to evaluate the removal of those environment specific reasons.

> is there a straightforward way to do this in FCM?

Do not use FCM with AGs, it's not supported and it can cause issues.

> The setting in the Failover tab in the Role Properties page in FCM seems to be doing nothing, even though it's set to allow failback immediately.

Failback works when a requisite cluster event occurs which could trigger failback. Since nothing is going on which would require that to occur, it's perfectly fine sitting where it is.

Comment: thank you again. Kindly clarify please : >>> In the cluster, there is the notion of a preference and this is for failover..... is a failover at cluster level independent of one at AG level or vice versa? When there is a failover at AG level, the same happens at Windows cluster level. Are you able to explain a bit more on that statement please? It is not possible for owning node to be A while primary replica in AG is B? is it?

Comment: Preference is the order in which the cluster will try to move resources, that's it. Has nothing to do with AGs. @PTL_SQL

Comment: thank you. Although I don't quite understand how the Windows failover does not affect the AG failover, I am much appreciative of your time. As far as I've been seeing so far, when I do a failover in AG, the owning node changes in line, in FCM

Comment: Correct, it will. When the failover occurs it'll check the preferred replicas and attempt them in the order they exist. AGs work differently than FCIs, AGs have more internal SQL specific items and logic. @PTL_SQL